# Delete query referencing 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, sql-delete

I have 3 tables tab1, tab2 and tab3.
in which the primary key of tab1 is foreign key to tab2
and 
primary key of tab 2 is foreign key to tab3

```
TAB1  |  TAB2     |  TAB3
-----------------------------
ID    |  ID       |  ID
      |  TAB1_ID  |  TAB2_ID
```

I want to delete a row in tab 3 in the following manner:

```
DELETE FROM TAB3 WHERE TAB2_ID=TAB2.ID AND TAB2.TAB1_ID=TAB1.ID
```

OR ELSE

```
DELETE FROM TAB3 WHERE TAB2_ID=TAB2.ID AND TAB2.TAB1_ID=3
```

Can anyone suggest a correct way to resolve this?

Comment: do you need to delete an ID which exist in three columns?

Comment: Making it clear, do you want to delete rows from TAB3 which match a specific TAB1.ID?

Comment: @LS_dev you are right. i want to delete rows from tab3 with specific tab1.id

Comment: I don't know MySQL specifics, but I would try `DELETE FROM tab3 JOIN tab2 ON tab3.tab2_id=tab2.id WHERE tab2.tab1_id=3`

Comment: `DELETE tab3 FROM tab3 JOIN tab2 ON tab3.tab2_id=tab2.id WHERE tab2.tab1_id=3` as @eggyal and according [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/delete.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multiple-table `DELETE` syntax:

1. > `DELETE FROM TAB3 WHERE TAB2_ID=TAB2.ID AND TAB2.TAB1_ID=TAB1.ID`

   ```
   DELETE TAB3
   FROM   TAB3
     JOIN TAB2 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.TAB2_ID
     JOIN TAB1 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.TAB1_ID
   ```
2. > `DELETE FROM TAB3 WHERE TAB2_ID=TAB2.ID AND TAB2.TAB1_ID=3`

   ```
   DELETE TAB3
   FROM   TAB3
     JOIN TAB2 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.TAB2_ID
   WHERE  TAB2.TAB1_ID = 3
   ```

However, if you configure your foreign keys to `CASCADE` deletions, then MySQL will automatically delete child rows whenever the parent records are deleted (perhaps this is what you want?).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM tab3 
    JOIN tab2 ON tab3.tab2_id = tab2.id
    JOIN tab1 ON tab2.tab1_id = tab1.id
```

Comment: i am getting this error while trying your query

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN tab2 ON tab3.tab2_id = tab2.id' at line 2`